# how to get first row and last column in nested loop

Tags: java, loops

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Masukkan nilai : ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        int kolom = input -1;
            for(int i=1;i<input;i++){
                for(int j=input;j>i;j--){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
```

output of code is :
[image: output of code is :]

but i want the output like :
[image]

so i think i need get the first row and last column

how to do that

Comment: Adding some `if` statements will do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Masukkan nilai : ");
int index = scanner.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
System.out.println();

for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
    for (int j = index; j > i; j--) {
        if (j == index || j == i + 1) {
            System.out.print("*");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(char c='*',i=0; i<input; c=' ',i++)
  for(int j=0; j<input-i; j++)
    System.out.print(j==0 ? "*" : j<input-i-1 ? c : "*\n");
```